# How can I access or enumerate available LEDs from kernel code (BeagleBone Black)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, led

I am trying to write a custom syscall handler that manipulates the LEDs on a BeagleBone Black board. I have gone through the kernel LED API (include/leds.h), but I am unable to find anything that'd give me a handle to the available LED devices or some other mechanism to manipulate (on/off/toggle) them. Most of the functions seem to require a led_classdev object, but I can't find a way of getting one.

I can do this from userspace using the /sys/class/leds/... interface. But I want to do something similar from kernel space. I am open to hard-coding any device names specific to BeagleBone Black as portability is not an issue.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why you can't do this from userspace, using gpio inrerface?

Comment: It's mostly an academic exercise. I need to manipulate the LEDs as a result of making a custom syscall. The syscall handler function in kernel space, therefore needs to access the LEDs.

Comment: Are this leds gpio connected?

Comment: Yes. The kernel has already been configured (not by me) with gpio/LED so that they are available under /sys/class/leds/beaglebone\:green\:usr[0-3]/.

Comment: The driver that instanciates the LEDs is **the owner** of them. If you would like to be an owner you have to instantiate the LEDs. Dirty hack is to open sysfs files in kernel (never do this!).

Comment: @0andriy So, I'd have to disable the other driver and create the LEDs in my code instead. Right?

Comment: As one approach, yes. Another can be one of: a) to hack LED framework to have needed API (not upstreamable solution of course, because we have sysfs ABI for it); b) drop LED framework completely and use GPIO lines directly (in the similar manner, you have to have a device driver which **owns** the lines).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to access/control the LEDs from kernel space - by creating a custom LED trigger. It doesn't give a way to enumerate available devices, and it requires the custom trigger to be assigned for an LED from user-space by writing to /sys/class/leds/foo/trigger. But it lets you manipulate the LEDs from kernel code once the trigger is assigned.

```
struct led_trigger *trigger;
...
led_trigger_register_simple("myled", &trigger); //create and register the trigger
...
//assign the trigger "myled" to the desired LED(s) from user-space
//by writing to the corresponding trigger files in /sys/class/leds/foo/
...
led_trigger_event(trigger, LED_FULL); //turn-on the LED(s) connected to the trigger
led_trigger_event(trigger, LED_OFF);  //turn-off
```

The creation and registering of trigger can be done in a module init, for example. Also, if one needs to manipulate multiple LEDs independently, then as far as I can see, one needs to create separate triggers for each LED.